# Hide jquery menu after click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have a simple function to show a dropdown menu.

This is a responsive menu, it only works with defined sizes on my media queries, that's why I want to hide submenu after click.

I want to click on one of the links and then this dropdown menu hides. I am aware of .hide() but I can't get it to work.

Any help?

I want to keep this code simple & clean.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                      <img src="img/menu.png" alt="mobile" width="50" height="50"/>
                        <li class="n1"><a href="#home">Principal</a></li>
                        <li class="n2"><a href="#services">Serviços</a></li>
                        <li class="n3"><a href="#team">Equipa</a></li>
                        <li class="n4"><a href="#contact">Contactos</a></li>
            </ul>
            <span>Euclides Style | 965648044</span>
        </nav>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("nav").click(function () {
    $(".navigation").toggleClass('open');
});
```

**UPDATE**

I used a simple solution:

```
$(".navigation a").click(function () {
            $(".navigation").removeClass('open');
    });
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Show us the HTML also

Answer (score 1):

`hide()` is working.
Try:

```
$("nav li").click(function () {
    $(".navigation").hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wkWEA/1/)

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552712/angular-4-mega-menu-is-not-closed-after-clicked-on-a-menu-inside-it @laaposto

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".navigation").fadeOut();
});
```

or you can try .hide() even .fadeOut();

Comment: This removes all my ".navigation" but I edited it to ".navigation .open". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that open class has `display: none` or `display: block` attribute (it depends on the starting state) will work fine.

Alternatively you can use `toggle` function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/uQg2X/

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552712/angular-4-mega-menu-is-not-closed-after-clicked-on-a-menu-inside-it @IrvinDominin

Answer (score 0):

```
$("nav").click(function () {
   $(".navigation").toggleClass('open');
});
```

and you should add some css

```
   .navigation{ display:'none'}
   .navigation.open{display:'block'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: it is not allowed to have a img-tag directly inside ul-tag. This is an example of a working code with some modifications:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hiding/showing navigation</title>

<style>
.closed{
    display: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("nav").click(function(){      
        $(".navigation").toggleClass('closed');
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <h1>The nav</h1>
    <ul class="navigation">                      
        <li class="n1"><a href="#home">Principal</a></li>
        <li class="n2"><a href="#services">Serviços</a></li>
        <li class="n3"><a href="#team">Equipa</a></li>
        <li class="n4"><a href="#contact">Contactos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span>Euclides Style | 965648044</span>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since when its not allowed? It's used quite more often then you think. Anyways, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `hide();` solution will totally hide the menu and will not show again the next time, the `toggle` solution will toggle all the other menus on the page, so here below is my solution, this effect will apply to all your dropdown menus on a page.

```
$(document).on("click",".dropdown-menu li a", function(){
    jQuery(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('div').removeClass('open');
});
```